# Overriding properties in Spring 3.1 with a local properties file

Tags: spring, deployment, properties

I am trying to override defaults found in my war file using a local properties file on the box I am deploying on.

```
<context:property-placeholder
  location="classpath*:*.properties, file:/var/myfolder/local.properties"
  ignore-resource-not-found="true"
  ignore-unresolvable="true" />
```

I've seen that this can be achieved by providing a file as the second location (comma separated).  Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to overwrite the properties.

I have tried defining the bean and setting locations using properties, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One approach is to separate them into two and use order

```
<context:property-placeholder
  location="classpath*:*.properties"
  ignore-resource-not-found="true"
  ignore-unresolvable="true"
  order ="0" />

<context:property-placeholder
  location="file:/var/myfolder/local.properties"
  ignore-resource-not-found="true"
  ignore-unresolvable="true"
  order="-1"/>
```

lowest order takes precedence

Comment: Thanks Manoj, I gave that a try, but unfortunately it didn't work for me for some reason.  I don't understand why.

Comment: Marked this one as the answer (although my code above works too).  The problem was having 2 application contexts

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem.  For some reason there are 2 application contexts in the system.  I need to investigate if there is a sane reason for this.  It worked as soon as I added the properties file to the other application context.

Thanks for your help!